# Enterprise Distribution

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution, enterprise-distribution, app-distribution

how to upload apps on apple enterprise store ?

1) i have an enterprise account of $299. and i want to upload my app to enterprise store.

2) i am doing this cause i want to distribute this to only specific users.
via MDM.

3) currently when i want to send ad-hoc build i have to add UDID in my provisioning profile which is a lengthy processure.

Please let me know the steps to upload apps on Enterprise store so that i can distribute my apps for specific users without need of adding there UDID in provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Enterprise Store". You need to use something like Hockey or Cisco Meraki (free solutions) that will host your content for you.

When building your application, use the enterprise distribution certificate and the enterprise distribution profile that you have created on https://developer.apple.com. You can then upload the archive/ipa that you build using these certificates to your desired distribution platform where any user with access can download and install the build.

Comment: can you provide me a little brief ?  i want to do In-House Enterprise Distribution and i don't want to repeatedly update the provisioning profile and add UDID each time ?

Comment: You don't have to if you build against an Enterprise Distribution Certificate and not the Ad-Hoc Distribution Certificate

Answer (score 0):

A service like HockeyApp is great for distributing to a limited group, but if you want to do real enterprise distribution you have to be the curator of your own "store".

It's actually very simple.

You need to have some page that hosts a link to your distribution. The link is of the form:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://<path to manifest file>/<manifest file name>.plist
```

The manifest file is a property list file that gives necessary details about the app.

It is of the format:

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>items</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>assets</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>kind</key>
                        <string>software-package</string>
                        <key>url</key>
                        <string>
                           <path to ipa file>.ipa
                        </string>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>kind</key>
                        <string>full-size-image</string>
                        <key>needs-shine</key>
                        <false/>
                        <key>url</key>
                        <string>
                            https:<path to icon file>/iTunes512.png
                        </string>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>kind</key>
                        <string>display-image</string>
                        <key>needs-shine</key>
                        <false/>
                        <key>url</key>
                        <string>
                            https://<path to icon file>/Icon57.png
                        </string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
                <key>metadata</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                    <string>com.your.app.id</string>
                    <key>bundle-version</key>
                    <string>##</string>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software</string>
                    <key>subtitle</key>
                    <string>
                        Subtitle for app.
                    </string>
                    <key>title</key>
                    <string>Title for app</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

It points to the location where your app is hosted.

The ipa file and all of the icon files have to be behind https.